# Using form data to dynamically construct url using ajax

Tags: ajax

I have the following ajax code that takes in 3 variables and passes them to a php file, and this is all fine and dandy. I want to do a redirect using the value stored in one of these variables.  I figured I could just do `window.location.href =` within the `success` in the ajax call, but for some reason, it doesn't seem to respond to the click, and simply does nothing.

Here is the ajax function, hope y'all can help!

```
$("#findItem").click(function() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
  $.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  url: 'http://plato.cs.virginia.edu/~aam3xd/cabbage/closestBuildingWeb.php',
  data: {
    foodItemId: $('#foodItem').val(),
    sentLongitude: position.coords.longitude,
    sentLatitude: position.coords.latitude
  },
  success: function(data){
    //$('#answer').html(data);
        //the following line doesn't seem to be executing....
    window.location.href = foodItemId+"/"+sentLatitude+"/"+sentLongitude;
  }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use your url into that window.location

```
window.location.href = "www.example.com/"+foodItemId+"/"+sentLatitude+"/"+sentLongitude;
```